# Toggle ascending and Toggle descending in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-hooks

I have a toggle button. When I click on the button, I was it to sort in ascending order, and when I click a second time I want to to sort into descending order. I can not get it do either.... not sure what it could be.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); //hold all the data
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false); //hold the state of the toggle

  const toggleTime = () => {
    let result = [];
    result = data.sort((a, b) => {
      return toggle
        ? a.order.deadline - b.order.deadline
        : b.order.deadline - a.order.deadline;
    });
    setToggle(result);
  };
```

Comment: if `toggle` is either `true` or `false`, `setToggle(result)` is not correct; it should be `setToggle(toggle => !toggle)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data` to store sorted data and the `toggle` is boolean to store sstate of the toggle:

```
const toggleTime = () => {
  const newToggle = !toggle;
  setToggle(newToggle);
  setData((preData) =>
    preData.sort((a, b) => {
      return newToggle
        ? a.order.deadline - b.order.deadline
        : b.order.deadline - a.order.deadline;
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for posting this! it worked for me on another project, where I was having issues impletmenting the sort... but now I understand the process better.!

Answer (score 0):

Set order state inside your component:

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState("ASC");
```

Toggle/change the state on the onClick of your toggle/changeOrder button:

```
<button
  onClick={() => setOrder((prevState) => prevState === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC") }
>
  Change order
</button>
```